# Socket.read() won't block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have the following code for a simple TCP server in Ruby:

```
# server.rb
require 'socket'

class Server
  def initialize(port)
    @port = port
  end

  def run
    Socket.tcp_server_loop(@port) do |connection|
      Thread.new do
        loop do
          puts "IO: #{IO.select([connection]).inspect} - data: #{connection.read}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

server = Server.new(16451)
server.run
```

As well as this trivial TCP client code:

```
# client.rb
require 'socket'

client = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 16451)
client.write('stuff')
```

It is my understanding that `connection.read` in `server.rb` should block if no data is present on the socket. However, when I run this on my macbook (OS X 10.12.5), it keeps spitting out the following output:

```
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: stuff
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
IO: [[#<Socket:fd 12>], [], []] - data: 
...
```

It seems that `IO.select` thinks there is data available to read on the socket, while no such data has been sent.

How can I achieve a blocking read when working with sockets in Ruby? Am I overlooking something?

---

Matt's answer pointed me in the right direction. For future readers, here's my new code.

```
# server.rb
require 'socket'

class Server
  BYTESIZE_OF_PACKED_INTEGER = [1].pack('i').bytesize

  def initialize(port)
    @port = port
  end

  def run
    Socket.tcp_server_loop(@port) do |connection|
      Thread.new do
        while packed_msg_bytesize = connection.read(BYTESIZE_OF_PACKED_INTEGER)
          msg_bytesize = packed_msg_bytesize.unpack('i').first
          msg = connection.read(msg_bytesize)
          puts msg
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

server = Server.new(16451)
server.run
```

And the client code.

```
# client.rb
require 'socket'

msg = 'stuff'
msg_bytesize = msg.bytesize
packed_msg_bytesize = [msg_bytesize].pack('i')

client = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 16451)
client.write(packed_msg_bytesize)
client.write(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` will block if there is no data, but not at EOF. The [`IO#read` docs say](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-read):

> When this method is called at end of file, it returns `nil` or `""`, depending on *length*: `read`, `read(nil)`, and `read(0)` return `""`, `read(positive_integer)` returns `nil`.

Since calling `read` on EOF doesn’t block, `select` will return the IO as readable straight away.

In your code the first call to `read` will block until *all* the data is read from the connection (i.e. the other end has closed it). From then it will be at EOF, so `select` will return it as ready, and `read` will return an empty string immediately.

Comment: do you know if there's any way to have it block at EOF? I'm playing around with implementing a simple chat server & client, and I was hoping to have a long-lived connection between client and server. The last thing I want is for the server to go to 100% cpu just actively looping over sockets that will have no data on them most of the time.

Comment: You’ll probably want to detect and remove those connections anyway, so you don’t want to skip over them. Note there is a difference between a socket with no data available (which is still connected to the other end) and a socket at EOF (which is disconnected and you just need to close it).